# HTML5 autocomplete and validation in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: html, ide, autocomplete, netbeans-7

I'm editing an HTML file in NetBeans 7.0. Is there a way to specify that I'm working with HTML5 document so it can do auto-complete and spell check accordingly to HTML5 spec?

For example, when I start typing `<br` it suggests to complete it with `<br>` and then close it with `</br>`. It's a bit annoying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is for strict version of html5... ie xml version.

If you want  to use html5 then 
 doesnt require a forward slash to close it.
Read HTML5 docs for specs

Answer (score 1):

yeah just edit the doctype definition at the beginning of the html document . put this

"!DOCTYPE html"

instead of this :

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

netbeans will then auto complete for you.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work for me. I have HTML5 definition but it still autocompletes with <br> instead of <br />.